# Is running speed affected by what weapon you have active?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

A friend told me this, and yes, it seems that depending on what weapon you have out, your running speed seems different.

Now I just want to know if it's my imagination or is it reality.

So there seems to be 3 tiers : Main weapon (SG,AR,SR,SMG), Side weapon (Pistols and Sawedoff) and Grenades/Melee

So taking the main weapon as a base, how much faster are Sideweapons and Grenades when sprinting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the Wiki](https://pubg.gamepedia.com/Movement_Speed), movement speed varies by weapon type, as well as being unarmed:

[image: speeds]

Apparently, you run fastest with a pistol out.  The difference between the weapons types is fairly minimal, but it is noticeable when playing with teammates who have no weapon equipped versus one with say a rifle out.

A pistol is .03m/s faster than throwables.  The wiki sources [this video](https://youtu.be/VCsdZayKRmg) that tests all of the possible equipment (as well as stances).

Comment: Why do pistols make you faster?

Comment: @JAB Obviously because by removing the hands and replacing it with a sleek pistol design, the human body is 0.3% more aerodynamic. The video it is sourced from says about it: "Pistols for whatever reason appeared to be a little bit faster in my recordings, but I think that might be [a] recording artifact. Or if it is, it is a 0.32% difference, so it is not significant in any way."